# Tensorflow loss change when adding noise to input images

Tags: tensorflow

I was wondering if it was typical to see huge spikes in the loss over time graph with models that are being fed images that get noise applied to them.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHK6a.png)

I was wondering if this is normal(look at the lines with DA which means data augmented), and if not what I should do to keep the loss from being so noisy. I'm guessing lowering the amount of noise I apply to the image, provided it keeps the same performance.

Thanks

edit: Whoops Just noticed I have train and valid losses flipped. Higher ones should be validation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course it is ! Especially if you do it 'online', so basically it never sees the same image twice.

However, I am wondering why you regularly get those big spikes in the top blue line, which isn't DA . It is difficult to say without more insight into your data and problem